# Can we write our own iterator in Java?

Tags: java, iterator

If I have a list containing `[alice, bob, abigail, charlie]` and I want to write an iterator such that it iterates over elements that begin with 'a', can I write my own ? How can I do that ?

Comment: You can. You have to implement the Iterator interface.

Comment: sure, it's just a normal interface. Proxying java.util for a JDO impl. involves quite a lot of custom iterators.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48109/simple-example-of-an-iterable-and-an-iterator-in-java

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Sure. An iterator is just an implementation of the [`java.util.Iterator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) interface. If you're using an existing iterable object (say, a `LinkedList`) from `java.util`, you'll need to either subclass it and override its `iterator` function so that you return your own, or provide a means of wrapping a standard iterator in your special `Iterator` instance (which has the advantage of being more broadly used), etc.

Comment: good answer.... +1 However you're not forced to subclass LinkedList. You can write a CustomIterator that it's instantiated with new CustomIterator(somelist), since interfaces tell nothing about constructors.

Comment: @Giacomo: That's what I meant by *"... or provide a means of wrapping a standard iterator in your special `Iterator` instance..."* (and thanks). :-)

Answer (score 214):

The best reusable option is to implement the interface Iterable and override the method iterator().

Here's an example of a an ArrayList like class implementing the interface, in which you override the method Iterator().

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class SOList<Type> implements Iterable<Type> {

    private Type[] arrayList;
    private int currentSize;

    public SOList(Type[] newArray) {
        this.arrayList = newArray;
        this.currentSize = arrayList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Type> iterator() {
        Iterator<Type> it = new Iterator<Type>() {

            private int currentIndex = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return currentIndex < currentSize && arrayList[currentIndex] != null;
            }

            @Override
            public Type next() {
                return arrayList[currentIndex++];
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
        return it;
    }
}
```

This class implements the Iterable interface using [Generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html). Considering you have elements to the array, you will be able to get an instance of an Iterator, which is the needed instance used by the "foreach" loop, for instance.

You can just create an anonymous instance of the iterator without creating extending Iterator and take advantage of the value of currentSize to verify up to where you can navigate over the array (let's say you created an array with capacity of 10, but you have only 2 elements at 0 and 1). The instance will have its owner counter of where it is and all you need to do is to play with hasNext(), which verifies if the current value is not null, and the next(), which will return the instance of your currentIndex. Below is an example of using this API...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create an array of type Integer
    Integer[] numbers = new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    // create your list and hold the values.
    SOList<Integer> stackOverflowList = new SOList<Integer>(numbers);

    // Since our class SOList is an instance of Iterable, then we can use it on a foreach loop
    for(Integer num : stackOverflowList) {
        System.out.print(num);
    }

    // creating an array of Strings
    String[] languages = new String[]{"C", "C++", "Java", "Python", "Scala"};

    // create your list and hold the values using the same list implementation.
    SOList<String> languagesList = new SOList<String>(languages);

    System.out.println("");
    // Since our class SOList is an instance of Iterable, then we can use it on a foreach loop
    for(String lang : languagesList) {
        System.out.println(lang);
    }
}
// will print "12345
//C
//C++
//Java
//Python
//Scala
```

If you want, you can iterate over it as well using the Iterator instance:

```
// navigating the iterator
while (allNumbers.hasNext()) {
    Integer value = allNumbers.next();
    if (allNumbers.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(value + ", ");
    } else {
        System.out.print(value);
    }
} 
// will print 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

The foreach documentation is located at http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html. You can take a look at a more complete implementation at my personal practice [google code](http://code.google.com/p/programming-artifacts/source/browse/trunk/workspaces/hacking/data-structures-impl/src/com/google/code/datastrut/list/ArrayList.java).

Now, to get the effects of what you need I think you need to plug a concept of a filter in the Iterator... Since the iterator depends on the next values, it would be hard to return true on hasNext(), and then filter the next() implementation with a value that does not start with a char "a" for instance. I think you need to play around with a secondary Interator based on a filtered list with the values with the given filter.

Comment: `for instance`, is that a pun?

Comment: 30 other people did not think that's a pun :)

Comment: It's a good practice to throw unsupported operation exception from us implemented methods. I think it's a good idea to throw unsupported operation exception from remove() method !

Comment: Sorry @darshan, but this solution is in regards to "how to write iterators"... If the focus was to "write perfectly written code", that would be there!

Comment: not clear why 'arrayList[currentIndex] != null'  check is required inside hasNext(). can someone please explain.

Answer (score 15):

Good example for Iterable to compute factorial

```
FactorialIterable fi = new FactorialIterable(10);
Iterator<Integer> iterator = fi.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
     System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

Short code for Java 1.8

```
new FactorialIterable(5).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Custom Iterable class

```
public class FactorialIterable implements Iterable<Integer> {

    private final FactorialIterator factorialIterator;

    public FactorialIterable(Integer value) {
        factorialIterator = new FactorialIterator(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return factorialIterator;
    }

    @Override
    public void forEach(Consumer<? super Integer> action) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(action);
        Integer last = 0;
        for (Integer t : this) {
            last = t;
        }
        action.accept(last);
    }

}
```

Custom Iterator class

```
public class FactorialIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {

    private final Integer mNumber;
    private Integer mPosition;
    private Integer mFactorial;


    public FactorialIterator(Integer number) {
        this.mNumber = number;
        this.mPosition = 1;
        this.mFactorial = 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return mPosition <= mNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        if (!hasNext())
            return 0;

        mFactorial = mFactorial * mPosition;

        mPosition++;

        return  mFactorial;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This is the complete code to write an iterator such that it iterates over elements that begin with 'a':

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class AppDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Bag<String> bag1 = new Bag<>();

        bag1.add("alice");
        bag1.add("bob"); 
        bag1.add("abigail");
        bag1.add("charlie"); 

        for (Iterator<String> it1 = bag1.iterator(); it1.hasNext();) {

            String s = it1.next();
            if (s != null)
                System.out.println(s); 
        }
    }
}
```

Custom Iterator class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Bag<T> {

    private ArrayList<T> data;

    public Bag() {

        data = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void add(T e) {

        data.add(e); 
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {

        return new BagIterator();
    }

    public class BagIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

        private int index; 
        private String str;

        public BagIterator() {

            index = 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {

             return index < data.size();  
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {

            str = (String) data.get(index); 
            if (str.startsWith("a"))
                return (T) data.get(index++); 
            index++; 
            return null; 
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can implement your own Iterator.  Your iterator could be constructed to wrap the Iterator returned by the List, or you could keep a cursor and use the List's get(int index) method.  You just have to add logic to your Iterator's next method AND the hasNext method to take into account your filtering criteria.  You will also have to decide if your iterator will  support the remove operation.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the complete answer to the question.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

class ListIterator implements Iterator<String>{
    List<String> list;
    int pos = 0;

    public ListIterator(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        while(pos < list.size()){
            if (list.get(pos).startsWith("a"))
                return true;
            pos++;
        }
        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public String next() {
        if (hasNext())
            return list.get(pos++);
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
}

public class IteratorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("alice", "bob", "abigail", "charlie");
        ListIterator itr = new ListIterator(list);

        while(itr.hasNext())
            System.out.println(itr.next()); // prints alice, abigail
    }
}
```

- `ListIterator` is the iterator for the array which returns the elements that start with 'a'.
- There is no need for implementing an Iterable interface. But that is a possibility.
- There is no need to implement this generically.
- It fully satisfies the contract for hasNext() and next(). ie if hasNext() says there are still elements, next() will return those elements. And if hasNext() says no more elements, it returns a valid `NoSuchElementException` exception.

Comment: I think your implementation looses the main advantage of iterators which is constant time complexity of hasNext() and next()

Comment: @Quade. hasNext and next never can be constant time both. Imagine a list with no match. The list has to be iterated all the way till figuring out there is not match. How can that be constant?

Comment: Nice answer, and actually, the `next` should still run in constant time (depending on the list implementation though). And @Ayoub Omari, the while loop introduced in the `hasNext` is an unavoidable computation that has to be done at some point anyways to shift the position for filtering, so having that done in the `hasNext` method is the same as doing the filtering outside of the iterator. You would have had to code that either way