# Nested Iterator Class

Tags: java, iterator

I have a class 'Deck', that creates an ArrayList called deck.
I'm trying to create a **nested Iterator class** that traverses the Cards in reverse order.

```
public class Deck {

    //Nested Iterator class to traverse the Cards in reverse order
    public abstract class DeckIterator implements Iterator<Card>{

        ListIterator it = deck.listIterator(deck.size());

        //Iterate in reverse.
        while(it.hasPrevious()) { //errors
            //System.out.println(it.previous());
            return it.previous();
        }  
    }
}
```

I have tried the suggestions below but I am still having no luck...
Instead of copying One ArrayList to another in reverse order, i'd rather Iterate over the existing ArrayList in the Outer Class. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with this!

Comment: If you really want to write an "Iterator" you just implement the interface. But why?

Comment: try `DeckIterator implements Iterator<Card>`

Comment: I see no proof you have even ***attempted*** a solution on your own.

Comment: See this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102499/iterating-through-a-list-in-reverse-order-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly make `Deck` implement `Iterable<Card>`, this will require you to implement the `iterator()` method. Make that method return an instance of your nested `DeckIterator` class.

```
@Override
public Iterator<Card> iterator()
{
    return new DeckIterator(deck);
}
```

Then make `DeckIterator` implement `Iterator<Card>` and implement the `hasNext()`, `next()` and `remove()` methods.

```
private static class DeckIterator implements Iterator<Card>
{

private int nextCard;
private final List<Card> cards;

public DeckIterator(List<Card> cards)
{
    this.cards = cards;
    this.nextCard = cards.size() - 1;
}

@Override
public boolean hasNext()
{
    if (nextCard < 0)
        return false;
    return true;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public Card next()
{
    if (hasNext())
        return cards.get(nextCard--);
    return null;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public void remove()
{

}
}
```

Then use,

```
Iterator<Card> iterator = yourDeck.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext())
{
 Card card = iterator.next();
}
```

To iterate backwards over the deck.

However you dont need to create your own `Iterator` if you just want to iterate in reverse `ListIterator` can do it for you.

```
ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
// Do whatever you do with your deck :P

ListIterator<Card> li = deck.listIterator(deck.size());

// Iterate in reverse.
while(li.hasPrevious()) 
{
  Card card = li.previous();
  // Do stuff with the card
}
```

Comment: This is what i was aiming for except the 'while' errors with "illegal start of type, package li does not exist, <identifier> expected, ';' expected, missing return statement

Comment: updated my answer, now the iterator should iterate in reverse

Answer (score 0):

[Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) is an *interface*, and as such you need to implement the methods in it. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849154/can-we-write-our-own-iterator-in-java) for more information.

However, perhaps the simplest thing is to create a method in your `Deck` that

1. creates a copy of the collection but in reverse order
2. returns an iterator over *that* collection

Note that since you're now iterating over a copy of the original collection it should be unaffected by another thread adding/removing cards from the desk.

Comment: might want to add the text of the solution.  There have been a good deal of posts getting flagged/removed for "link only" answers

Answer (score 0):

With Guava you can reverse the list and iterate over the result.
Look at:
http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29

That should be easy enough and shouldn't cause to much changes/refactoring.