# Iterable as a return type

Tags: java, iterable

I'm having trouble understanding a method. I have methods that I need to fill out, but I don't really understand the first one. How can Iterable be a return type and how is it used ? An example would be great..

```
@Override
public Iterable<ClientInterface> getNeighbours() {

    return null;
}

@Override
public void addNeighbour(ClientInterface newNeighbour){
    //TODO Implement me!
}

@Override
public void removeNeighbour(String clientID) {
    //TODO Implement me!
}
```

Comment: Try adding a List to your class as a private member and use it in all 3 of those methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849154/can-we-write-our-own-iterator-in-java

Comment: What makes you think Iterable couldn't be a return type? Sure it can.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like your class should have an implementation of `Iterable<ClientInterface>` as a class member, like ArrayList.

Let's use this as an example:

```
public class Bus {
   private ArrayList<Person> riders;
   ... //constructors and other methods

   public Iterable<Person> getRiders() {

     return riders;

   }
   ... //other methods
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Everything can be a return type: an enum, a class, an interface, an int, an exception etc.

`Iterable` is an `interface` which could be used to use the return in a foreach call (that's why you can use `for(T something : AnArrayList)` because `ArrayList<T>` implements `Iterable<T>`)

Now, my answer contains an example:

We have a method `getNeighbours` which returns `Iterable<ClientInterface>`

```
public Iterable<ClientInterface> getNeighbours()
{
    return new Iterable<ClientInterface>();
}
```

Well, ok since `Iterable` is just an interface we need to implement methods or use an implementation.

Since it's something which we should do manually we should implement the methods by ourself.

The only method (in Java8, there are 3 methods but we will ignore it) is `iterator()` which returns an `iterator`.

```
public Iterable<ClientInterface> getNeighbours()
{
    return new Iterable<ClientInterface>()
    {
        @Override
        public Iterator<ClientInterface> iterator()
        {
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

`Iterator` is another interface which is used to provide the logic to iterate over the collection, a list of items etc.

We are forced to implements two methods: **hasNext** and **next**

`hasNext` is used to determinate if there are more items to iterate over, `next` is used to iterate over it.

```
public Iterable<ClientInterface> getNeighbours()
{
    return new Iterable<ClientInterface>()
    {
        @Override
        public Iterator<ClientInterface> iterator()
        {
            return new Iterator<ClientInterface>()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean hasNext()
                {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public ClientInterface next()
                {
                    return null;
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

We here need to remember which was our last position so we would create a field inside our Iterator.

```
public Iterable<ClientInterface> getNeighbours()
{
    return new Iterable<ClientInterface>()
    {
        @Override
        public Iterator<ClientInterface> iterator()
        {
            return new Iterator<ClientInterface>()
            {
                private int position;

                @Override
                public boolean hasNext()
                {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public ClientInterface next()
                {
                    return null;
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

Here the problem: What we should iterate? It depends to you, an example could be:

```
public Iterable<ClientInterface> getNeighbours()
{
    return new Iterable<ClientInterface>()
    {
        @Override
        public Iterator<ClientInterface> iterator()
        {
            return new Iterator<ClientInterface>()
            {
                private int position;
                private ClientInterface[] items = new ClientInterface[]{new ClientInterface(), new ClientInterface()};

                @Override
                public boolean hasNext()
                {
                    return position != items.length;
                }

                @Override
                public ClientInterface next()
                {
                    if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
                    return items[position++];
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

Note here how we created an array of items and used our two methods `hasNext` and `next` to provide a way to iterate over it.

Every call of `next` increment the internal pointer, and our hasNext method just checks if the pointer reached the end of the array.

Collections like `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` etc. already did the job for you and better (implements `remove` method) you can get this iterator by using `ArrayList.iterator()`

Now you could write something like:

```
for (ClientInterface el : yourClass.getNeighbours())
{
    System.out.println(el);
}
```

Comment: thanks for great explanation!

private ClientInterface[] items = new ClientInterface[]{new ClientInterface(), new ClientInterface()};how its possiable to create an object from interface ?and when i want to add more clientInterface then what happens ?

Comment: In this cass you don't create an interface, you create an anonymous class which implements the interface (note the {}) in this case it was an example anyway your data should be inside the outside class not in the iterator or you will create a copy of it everytime

Answer (score 3):

`Iterable<T>` is an interface. What this means is that when you receive it as a return value from a method, you actually receive an *implementation* of it. So, although you don't know what the *name* of that implementation is (the name of the class that implements the `Iterable<T>` interface), you can still access the methods that it implements, and act upon it.

Some built-in implementations include `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `HashSet`, `PriorityQueue`, and `Stack`.

When you need to return an interface type, you must return an implementation of it.