# How can I fix this particular "Val cannot be reassigned" error?

Tags: android, kotlin, immutability, var, mutable

I have this code that keeps giving me a "Val cannot be reassigned" error but I can't seem to change the variable to a var instead of val. I simply want to be able to set a string value to my cell reference so I can access the values later like this `myStringsArrayList.add(deviceData.cellOne)`.

Here is my code:

```
val cells = listOf(
            deviceData.cellOne,
            deviceData.cellTwo,
            deviceData.cellThree,
            deviceData.cellFour,
            deviceData.cellFive,
            deviceData.cellSix,
            deviceData.cellSeven,
            deviceData.cellEight,
            deviceData.cellNine,
            deviceData.cellTen,
            deviceData.cellEleven,
            deviceData.cellTwelve,
            deviceData.cellThirteen,
            deviceData.cellFourteen
        )

        for ((i, cell) in cells.withIndex()) {
            val value = data[2 + i].toDouble() / 100 + 3.52
            val cellNumberString = (i + 1).toString()
            val formattedString = "Cell $cellNumberString: %.2fV".format(value)
            cell = formattedString // THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS (cell is a val)
        }
```

Does anyone know how I can get around this and achieve the functionality that I want?

I tried using a `listIterator()` but it hasn't seemed to work the way that I want it to.

Here is my attempt with the `listIterator()`:

```
val cells = mutableListOf(
            deviceData.cellOne,
            deviceData.cellTwo,
            deviceData.cellThree,
            deviceData.cellFour,
            deviceData.cellFive,
            deviceData.cellSix,
            deviceData.cellSeven,
            deviceData.cellEight,
            deviceData.cellNine,
            deviceData.cellTen,
            deviceData.cellEleven,
            deviceData.cellTwelve,
            deviceData.cellThirteen,
            deviceData.cellFourteen)

        val iterate = cells.listIterator()
        while (iterate.hasNext()) {
            var cell = iterate.next()
            val value = data[2 + iterate.nextIndex()].toDouble() / 100 + 3.52
            val cellNumberString = (iterate.nextIndex() + 1).toString()
            val formattedString = "Cell $cellNumberString: %.2fV".format(value)
            cell = formattedString
        }
```

Comment: Try `val cells = listOf().map { }`, where your conversion logic goes in the `map` lambda.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34608552/4778990) answer. It may be helpful.

Comment: @MichelFortes I read through that post and tried using a `listIterator()` but it's not really working. I will make an edit on my question so you can see. Maybe I'm not using it correctly? I need it to change the variable in my custom DeviceData object but it seems like I can't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make that a `var`, and there's no reason to anyway!

```
for ((i, cell) in cells.withIndex()) {
    ...
    cell = formattedString // THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS (cell is a val)
}
```

You're creating a `for` loop there on a collection, with an index, and giving it a block of code to run for each loop. So when the loop runs, you're provided with two parameters - the current item from the collection, and its index in that collection.

These are just internal variables for use in the loop - you can't reassign them, because they're the values being passed in. Even if you could, you'd just be changing the values of those local variables.

What you're probably trying to do is update the `cells` list, taking the current item in the loop, finding it in `cells`, and replacing it. You'd have to actually update `cells` to do that! Change the list itself. You could do that with `cells[i] = formattedString` - **but** because you're currently iterating over that `cells` collection, you shouldn't modify it!

You could copy the source list, but the typical Kotlin way is to create a new list, using `map` (which transforms values):

```
cells.mapIndexed { i, cell ->
    val value = data[2 + i].toDouble() / 100 + 3.52
    val cellNumberString = (i + 1).toString()
    // last expression is the return value, i.e. the formatted string
    "Cell $cellNumberString: %.2fV".format(value)
}
```

That will spit out a new (immutable) list where each cell has been *mapped* to that formatted string version.

You could make `cells` a `var` and just reassign it:

```
cells = cells.mapIndexed { ... }
```

or just chain the map call when you initialise the `val`, so that end result is what gets assigned:

```
val cells = listOf(
    ...
).mapIndexed { ... }
```

---

But you're not actually using `cell` in that loop anyway, just using the index to generate values. [You can create a list like this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/constructing-collections.html#initializer-functions-for-lists):

```
val data = List(14) { i ->
    val value = data[2 + i].toDouble() / 100 + 3.52
    // you can calculate the index inside the string by using braces
    "Cell ${i + 1}: %.2fV".format(value)
}
```

It all depends whether you need to keep that list of `devicedata` values around for anything (if so use it to create *another* list)

Comment: Wow, I like this solution quite a bit! I ended up using the chained map call as you suggested, and it worked great!

Answer (score 1):

You may wanna use Interator this way:

```
val list = mutableListOf("One", "Two", "Three", "Four")
println(list.joinToString(" "))

val iterator = list.listIterator()
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    val value = iterator.next()
    if (value == "Two") {
        iterator.set("xxxxxx")
    }
}
println(list.joinToString(" "))
```

Use the 'set' method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I actually totally forgot there was a set() function!