# Circle List, iterate until end or break, remember iteration

Tags: java, dictionary, iteration

*This is a simplified example of how it will be used!*

A map with n-elements (in this example there are three; `One`, `Two` and `Three`). The map is defined as `<String, DecrementableInteger>` were the later is a wrapper for a mutable integer.

```
class DecrementableInteger
{
    private int timeLeftMax;
    private int timeLeft;

    public DecrementableInteger (int v) {
        timeLeft = v;
        timeLeftMax = v;
    }

    public void update (int v) {
        timeLeft -= v;
    }

    public int get () {
        return timeLeft;
    }

    public void reset () {
        timeLeft = timeLeftMax;
    }
}
```

Then there is the usage of it.

```
class Test
{
    private final Map<String, DecrementableInteger> integers = new CircleHashMap<>(); //?
    private String activeKey = null;

    Test () {
        integers.put("One", new DecrementableInteger(4));
        integers.put("Two", new DecrementableInteger(1));
        integers.put("Three", new DecrementableInteger(2));
    }

    void update () {
        if (activeKey == null) {
            for (Entry<String, DecrementableInteger> e : integers.entrySet()) {
                e.getValue().update (1);
                if (e.getValue().get () <= 0) {
                    System.out.println(e.getKey() + " just finished, resetting.");
                    e.getValue().reset();
                    activeKey = e.getKey();
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(activeKey + " did their thing, continuing!");
            activeKey = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The `update` method is called many times every second.

The first iteration will give the following result.

1. One => 3
2. Two => 0, `Two just finished, resetting.` Two => 1

**Iteration broke, continue at `Three` next time.**

3. Three => 1

**Iteration done, start over at `One` next time.**

4. One => 2,
5. Two => 0, `Two just finished, resetting.` Two => 1

**Iteration broke, continue at `Three` next time.**

5. Three => 0, `Three just finished, resetting.` Three => 2

**Iteration done, start over at `One` next time.**

6. One => 1
7. ...

Meaning the code will need have the following qualities:

- The Map needs to remember its order, it can not shuffle them around.
- The code needs to remember were it left off; currently in `activeKey`
- The iteration needs to be able to start from `activeKey`

Is there a efficient and neat solution to a `CircleList`? If so, what would that solution look like.

Comment: Why are you using map? Do you select value based on its key or not?

Comment: In this simplified example I do not. However selection is used on the full code. Which I can not really post here due to its healthy length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to use a Map, or could you use a List?

If it needs to be a Map, you should use TreeMap, as TreeMap has defined ordering. Then you need to create a special Iterator, which essentially traverses the tree, and goes back to element 1 when it reaches the end.

Comment: More information can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849154/can-we-write-our-own-iterator-in-java).