# Terminate a stream each time next() is called

Tags: java, java-stream, guava

I'm not sure if a question was already asked. I'm still new to Java's Stream API and Google's Guava.

I would like to use Java's Stream API to transform or map one object to another one item at a time. It seems like this is different than collect. It seems like collect would convert all items in the stream when it's called instead of one at a time. Ideally, I would like to provide an iterable that allows one item to be converted when something like next() is called.

Maybe it would look something like this:

```
private Iterable<ObjectA> getIterable(Iterable<ObjectB> itemsToConvert) {
  return itemsToConvert.map(mappingFunction);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Iterable<ObjectA> myIterable = getIterable(itemsFromSomewhere);
  // do the conversion here
  ObjectA myItem = myIterable.next();
}
```

Is there a way to do this in Java using the Stream API? If not, is there a way to do this using Google's Guava?

Comment: Maybe add a pseudo code example on what you want to achieve...

Comment: @Erik is this what you are may be looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932061/convert-iterable-to-stream-using-java-8-jdk

Comment: @Eugene I think so. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh you want to hook into the `Iterator.next` method. I don't think that is possible. You could however manipulate `myItem` since you got the reference you need e.g.

```
 ObjectA myItem = myIterable.next();
 manipulateObject(myItem); // change stuff do stuff
```

However, since you want the next() method to convert the next item in the iterator, you should implement your own `Iterator` and override it like it is explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5849625/4467208

Comment: The pseudo code doesn't solve my problem but the link you gave does

Comment: For the purpose of quality here on stackoverflow, I recommend you write your own answer and check it as the accepted one, or edit the answer from @Murat K, but leave it as the accepted answer.